# restsharp unsuccessful post

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

I'm trying to consume a rest service(wcf) using restsharp

This is my service

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method="POST", UriTemplate = "/PEmploy", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
        Employee PostGetEmploy(Employee emp);
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Employee
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int EmpNo { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string EmpName { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string DeptName { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is how I call it

```
    var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:14437/Service.svc");
    var request = new RestRequest("XmlService/PEmploy", Method.POST);
    myRef.Employee emp = new myRef.Employee() { EmpNo = 101, EmpName = "Mahesh", DeptName = "CTD" };
    request.AddParameter("Employee", emp);
    RestResponse<myRef.Employee> response = (RestResponse<myRef.Employee>)client.Execute<myRef.Employee>(request);
```

and this is the exception that I get

```
    Exception:Caught: "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1." (System.Xml.XmlException)
    A System.Xml.XmlException was caught: "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."
```

I've tried serialization but still got the same exception.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I added

```
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
```

and this did the trick.

**Full Code**

```
var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:14437/Service.svc");
var request = new RestRequest("XmlService/PEmploy", Method.POST);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
myRef.Employee emp = new myRef.Employee() { EmpNo = 101, EmpName = "Mahesh", DeptName = "CTD" };
request.AddParameter("Employee", emp);
RestResponse<myRef.Employee> response = (RestResponse<myRef.Employee>)client.Execute<myRef.Employee>(request);
```

Comment: For future visitors: he added request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;